# jQuery/JavaScript Undefined Function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a script for my slider called `Camera`. Unfortunately it keeps loading and gives me the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating `'$('#camera_wrap').camera'`)

The piece of code where that is involved is as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#camera_wrap').camera({
        loader: true,
        pagination: false,
        minHeight: '',
        thumbnails: false,
        height: '54.6875%',
        caption: true,
        navigation: true,
        fx: 'simpleFade'
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included the plugin?

Comment: You're calling the plugin when it's not really there !

Comment: It cannot find your camera plugin, see that you have included it and it loads before this script is called.

Comment: is jQuery loaded before the plugin?

Comment: Show the script including.

Comment: What they said... also, a link or jsfiddle might be handy.

Comment: Not a bad first question IMO, describes the problem clearly and includes most of the relevant details and code as far as the OP knows. Just because the question is a beginner one doesn't mean it should be downvoted

Comment: Press F12 reload the page and open the console window, then go to network tab reload page and tell us if Jquery makes it to the client...

Answer (score 0):

One of the functions you call isn't actually a function.

There are only two or three (relevant) function calls: `$(..)` and `.camera(...)` and maybe `.ready(...)`. 
.
So either:

- You don't have jQuery loaded before this script is executed. In that case `$(...)` does not exist. You should load the jQuery library before (higher up in the code of the page) before this script is executed.
- You have jQuery loaded in compatibility mode, so it doesn't register `$(...)`. In that case, you can replace the shorthand `$` with `jQuery`, so you can call `jQuery.ready(....)`.
- You didn't load the camera plugin. It doesn't matter much where you load it, since the code that calls the function is only called when the whole page has loaded, but you need to include that library in your page as well.
- You didn't include any of the other libraries, or you included them in the wrong order. [The website says](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/#usage_anchor):

> As you can see in the examples themselves, before the Camera plugin,
>   you must call **jQuery** in the head [sic]*) of your document: without jQuery the
>   slideshow doesn't work.
>
> Then you must call **jQuery Easing plugin** and **jQuery Mobile plugin**.
>   *After that* you must call Camera plugin and initialize the function
>   camera with the simply method `jQuery('YOUR_TARGET').camera();`

*) *(As Sparky mentioned in comments, you don't strictly need to load jQuery in the head, as long as you load it before the script is executed).*

Comment: jQuery does not have to be called from the `head` of the document.  As long as a DOM ready event handler function is properly used and the plugins are included after jQuery, jQuery could also be included within the `body` of the document.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't say anywhere that is should be loaded in the head. It should be loaded before the posted script is executed. So if OP's script is in the body, jQuery can be loaded in the body as well, as long as it's still before the script. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: Yes, but you quoted the website which said _"you must call jQuery in the head"_.  I simply clarified that this is not entirely true.

Comment: Ah, I see. :) You are right. That quote, though 'official' is not entirely true.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error occurs while evaluating `$('#camera_wrap').camera`, we can assume you have loaded jQuery correctly as this is called inside `$(document).ready()`.

So the problem must be that jQuery can't 'see' your plugin script at the time when it needs to.

Make sure you include the `Camera` plugin script **after** jQuery and **before** your code which uses it. If you don't know how to do this please edit your question and include all of the HTML for the page you are working on.